# Telegram - Display Emergency phone number

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Is there a way to display (as clickable) emergency phone number in message sended by BOT on Telegram?
If I send a message wih (eg.) "+5561789485745", automaticly Telegram turns it into "clickable". But it seems Telegram check the "+", the country code but also the length. So if I want to use a number like "193" (emergency in Brasil), for Telegram this is not a valide number.
According to some RFC, it must be "+55-193" but this change nothing. I also tried to use URL so "tel:" but "tel:" is not recognised by Telegram.
Any idea? Or maybe I have to create a link to a Web page which will have a "tel:" link?
Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about the native applications on iOS and Android, is that correct?

Comment: All cases WiGeeky. Desktop o App, result is the same. As Telegram dont' use the "tel:" of HTML, it seems to rely on size and "+" and so short numbers fail.

Comment: I understand that Telegram doesn't support tel: in its markdown/html formattings, have you tried providing a url button? Did that work?

Comment: Well what have done is providing a URL button opening a web page on my web site on which I have a page with a JS refresh using a url with "tel:". Not very "clean" but it works :)